# Removing multiple select option from drop down

Tags: php, jquery

Does anyone knows how to remove multiple `option`s from form drop down?  I want to read data from database, and depending on its value remove some `option`s.

```
<select name="year">
    <option value="1">First year/option>
    <option value="2">Second year</option>
    <option value="3">Third year</option>
</select>
```

After I read data from the database, I would like to remove some values based on the data's value. So if the data value is `3`, I want to remove values `1` and `2` from thr drop down list..

Comment: you need to dynamically generate your form in a `while` loop while fetching data from db

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) to filter out elements on custom conditions.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/QTw8X/)**

```
$('[name=year] option').filter(function(){
    return this.value != '3'
}).remove();
```

or

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/QTw8X/1/)**

```
$('select :not(option[value=3])').remove();
```

**Edit** based on comments, *to filter elements have values less then given value.*

Use `<` operator instead of == then and treat the value as number instead of string,

```
$('[name=year] option').filter(function(){
    return parseInt(this.value) < 3
}).remove();
```

Comment: Tnx this helped me, but I forgot to ask in question: If the value from db was 2, i want to remove value 1. So i want to remove lower values then the value from database.

Comment: Use < operator instead of == then and treat the value as number instead of string.,   return parseInt(this.value) < 3

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is have 2 sections of the same dropdown box. Inside the sections you need to dynamically generate the options omitting the ones which you do not need.

```
   if($data_from_db){
      <select name="year">
       <option value="1">First year/option>
       <option value="2">Second year</option>
      </select>
   }
   else{
     <select name="year">
       <option value="1">First year/option>
       <option value="2">Second year</option>
       <option value="3">Third year</option>
     </select>
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this

```js
$("select option[value!='3']").remove();
```